# Blowfish encryption and decryption in C

Tags: c, algorithm, blowfish

So here is my C program, I can't figure out why I can't decrypt the encrypted string. I wanted to write a small C program which takes a string, encrypts, then takes the encrypted string and with the supplied key, decrypts. Two questions:
A)What am I doing wrong here?
B)How is the key stored, that is, if I am now working on a new encryption and the user wants to decrypt the previous text, when he supplies the password, would blowfish then know how to decrypt it?

Here is documentation for blowfish:
http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/blowfish.html
and now my program:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "blowfish.h"
#include "bf_pi.h"
#include "bf_locl.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
 {
    char from[128], to[128];
    int len = 128;
    BF_KEY key;
    char temp_buf[16];
    int n = 0;          /* internal blowfish variables */
    unsigned char iv[8];        /* Initialization Vector */
    /* fill the IV with zeros (or any other fixed data) */
    memset(iv, 0, 8);


    printf("input password: ");
    scanf("%s", &temp_buf);

    strcpy(from, "ABCDEFGHTHISISTHEDATA"); //ENCRYPT THIS

    BF_set_key(&key, 16, temp_buf);

    BF_cfb64_encrypt(from, to, len, &key, iv, &n, BF_ENCRYPT);
    printf("encrypted to -->  %s\n", to); //SUCCESSFULY ENCRYPTED


    BF_cfb64_encrypt(from, to, len, &key, iv, &n, BF_DECRYPT);
    printf("File %s has been decrypted to --> %s \n",from,  to); //FAILS DOES NOT DECRYPT
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you're supposed to switch the `from` and `to` variables:

```
//as WhozCraig mentioned, fill in n and iv again before decryption
n = 0;          /* internal blowfish variables */
/* fill the IV with zeros (or any other fixed data) */
memset(iv, 0, 8);

BF_cfb64_encrypt(to, from, len, &key, iv, &n, BF_DECRYPT);
printf("File %s has been decrypted to --> %s \n",to,  from); //FAILS DOES NOT DECRYPT
```

> Retaining the original IV (which isn't hard;
>   it was all zeros) and resetting n to zero before the decryption will
>   get what the OP wants  - WhozCraig

Comment: Can you post the results?

Comment: input password: hello
encrypted to -->  Z???/?w?N Z>j4??<Vc??Wj???χ??6?+??@[=?+V??uyd%_?s_O??4Z??dJCw??? G?.s'?o??Io????1?ldG?aM{~?u??
                                                                                                                    ;B???RD?O ???S̆Q???ABCDEFGHTHISISTHEDATA
File o;b?Qwr?THISISTHEDATA has been decrypted to --> LANG

Comment: I don't see the download for the source code.  Can you direct me to it?

Comment: Can you copy my code and compile it. I don't know what you mean by download the source code; the code is in the posting?

Comment: I don't have the following:  "blowfish.h", "bf_pi.h", "bf_locl.h"

Comment: This is partly correct. Retaining the original IV (which isn't hard; it was all zeros) and resetting `n` to zero before the decryption will get what the OP wants.